# Execution time: 94.293220043182 in magento2

Tags: magento2, exception

I have install fresh magento2.2.2 version in my local system
When I am going to run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
command it's give me Execution time error...
i have attached screen shot regarding error[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because , This is not an error

Answer (score 4):

It's not an error, it's a success message, unfortunately marked red.

It seems to be an issue with Magento 2.2.0 to 2.2.3 only. It has already been fixed on GitHub and will be available in Magento 2.2.4 (see https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/13709).

Comment: ok thanks,But After I remove Static->front end folder and Var->cache,Var->view_preprocessed,var->page_cache ....showing some process(..........) before but currently it's not showing.....is is ok?

Comment: I'd assume it's okay as it has taken 95 seconds which is in the reasonable range. Did you notice any other problems?

Comment: how to change color of the error...any command

Comment: Have a look at the pull request I mentioned. The new Magento version is scheduled to come out in the beginning of May 2018.